# How to Prevent JSP Page Refresh

Tags: java

Please can any one help me with an idea on how to prevent a JSP page refresh when an request parameter is triggered. Below is my line of code:

```
String action = request.getParameter("cmd");
  if (action == null) {
                 System.out.println("You are here2");
                action = "";
                }
 else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("examSelected")){

            System.out.println("The Exam ID of the Long value is " + ExamId);
           ArrayList<Subject> subjectName = new ArrayList<Subject>();
```

I want when the action is on examSelected, let the JSP page not refresh.
Thanks in response.

Comment: What do you mean by _let the JSP page not refresh_ ?

Comment: Let the JSP page not reload. When ever the action is on examSelected it keeps reloading and thereafter it resets the value on the JSP page.

Comment: and what does _JSP page not reload_ ? Do you want to say, when the user clicks a particular button/link related to `examSelected`, the page should not refresh ?

Comment: Exactly, you got it. Because the examSelected holds a combobox value that is being wiped off when the page is refreshed

Comment: Refer below Artemis's answer. If you don't want to post back the complete page, then you need to use AJAX

Comment: The netbeans tutorials is talking about autocomplete on a form. And not on preventing page reload/refresh

Comment: @PatrickNdu Your issue is not about not reloading the page. It's about keeping the form's values after sending a request. I suggest you show your JSP code.

Comment: This is my JSP code:<td width="121"><select name="txtExam" id="ExamId"onChange="javascript:doSubmit('examSelected',document.getElementById('ExamId').value);"><option>[Select an Exam First]</option><%if (exams != null && !exams.isEmpty()){for (Iterator iterator = exams.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){exam =(Exam)iterator.next();
 examservice.getAllRecordsByParameterId(Subject.class, Exam.class, exam.getId(), 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);%><option value="<%=exam.getId()%>"><%= exam.getName()%></option><%
            }

Answer (score 0):

If you want you update info o the page without refreshing it you can just use Ajax for updating info on the page.

Here is detailed tutorial that describes how to to ajax requests.https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/ajax-quickstart.html